# How do you print a string in C character by character?

Tags: c, printf, character

Using printf and without using any looping or branching?

Comment: what do you mean character by character? and how does it different from using `printf("%s", var);` ?

Comment: What do you mean character by character ? And why don't you want to use a loop ?

Comment: `char *str = "bla"; printf("%c%c%c\n", str[0], str[1], str[2]);`

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is your friend:

```
int print_char_by_char(char * p)
{
  *p && print_char_by_char(p+1);
  printf("%c", *p);
  return 1;
}

int main(void)
{
  print_char_by_char("alk");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice, but logical `&&` is considered branching, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Extending the answer of @alk, you can use recursion and pointers to function in order to avoid the use of logical operators:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void dummy(char *p);
void print(char *p);

void (*fp[])(char *) = {dummy, print};

void dummy(char *p)
{
    (void)p;
}

/**
 *  Read *p as bool (0 or 1) using bitwise operators
 *  Call print() recursively if 1
 *  Call dummy() if 0 and exits from function
 */
void print(char *p)
{
    char i = *p;

    i |= i >> 4;
    i |= i >> 2;
    i |= i >> 1;
    printf("%c", *p);
    fp[i & 1](p + 1);
}

int main(void)
{
    print("Hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: C doesn't have a native type bool that will only be zero or 1. Hence i will be zero or more-than-zero and cause an error when not 1 in the selection of the function. It will work with an array of 255 entries: entry zero has dummy, all others have print_char_by_char. (You can make this array global.)

Comment: that means this only works in C99, not in older chainsaw C versions (where the programmer must do everything himself) and in those older versions with macros, the macro will do a (x?1:0) which is a branch and so violates the assignment (and the built-in C99 type bool makes the compiler generate this branch, hence, also violation of the assignment).

Comment: Or just replace `bool i = *p;` with `int i = !!*p`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, I didn’t know that bool was implemented in this way, thanks for pointing that

Comment: @alk,  I think `!` is also a violation of the assignment, it is possible to obtain a boolean `0` or `1` using bitwise operators?

Answer (score 0):

Well, your question is

> How do you print a string in C character by character?
>
> Using printf and without using any looping or branching?

The simplest answer for that is

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
  {
    char a[]="blablabla";
    printf("%s",a);
    return 0;
  }
```

This is the answer to your question. If this is not what you wanted, then **Specify your exact question giving more details**.

Comment: This is not character-by-character. It prints a string in one go.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie , then what do you mean by "character by character"

Comment: @arun-a-s, this means the pogrammer programs to print one character, then for example increments the string pointer, then programs to print another character, etc. For example using printf("%c",*p); See other examples.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie , well I understand that, but I believe this answer is more than enough for a question with such less details. If the OP had specified what purpose it is for or gave an example of what should be done, then I would not have posted this. But for the current question, I believe this answer does that ( I mean, doing it like this will have the same effect as the other answers unless there are certain conditions to be met, which clearly have not been specified ).

Answer (score 0):

@qwe2004, tell your professor that the Stack Overflow community agrees that it can't be done. If he says it can be done, we are all interested in seeing his clever and cunning way of doing it, and learn. (Tell him also we will be critical of hidden branching and logical tests.)

Comment: It can be done without logical operators,  take a look to my answer.